# C# + telnet process w/ redirected standard streams quits immediately

Tags: c#, redirect, process

I'm trying to do a 'scripted telnet' project in C# (something vaguely resembling the [Tcl Expect](http://expect.nist.gov/) package) for which I need to start a telnet process and redirect (and process) its stdin/stdout streams.

The problem is, the spawned telnet process quits immediately after starting (it does start, however).
If I try to do the same with -say- cmd.exe, it works.

Does the telnet implementation require an interactive stdin? Does this concept even exist in Windows?

I'm running Win7 64 bit, could this contribute to the dscribed behaviour?

Here's the snippet i use:

```
Process m_process = new Process();
m_process.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(
                 @"C:\Windows\system32\telnet.exe", "towel.blinkenlights.nl");

//required to redirect stdXXX
m_process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
m_process.StartInfo.ErrorDialog = false;

m_process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
m_process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
m_process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;

Thread.Sleep(50);
Console.WriteLine(" exited? " + m_process.HasExited);
```

The output is:

> exited? True

If I use this:

```
...
m_process.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(
                @"C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe", "");
...
```

the output is

> exited? False

Comment: `telnet.exe` is not part of windows 7 x64 and is not located at `c:\windows\system32`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All that your experiments with `cmd.exe` prove is that you're successfully launching `cmd.exe`. :-)

Have you tried doing `C:\Windows\system32\telnet.exe towel.blinkenlights.nl` in a command prompt window to make sure that works? Having done that, have you tried redirecting input to it from a file (e.g., `C:\Windows\system32\telnet.exe towel.blinkenlights.nl < filename`)?

I suspect that Windows' telnet may not be using stdin for its input, in order to handle terminal emulation.

I just tried a very simple and possibly naive experiment suggesting that that's the case, at least in XP 32-bit. I did this:

```
echo GET / | telnet www.google.com 80
```

...and it didn't work, whereas `telnet www.google.com 80` and then typing `GET /` and pressing enter does. A similar experiment with a tool that *does* read stdin (`nslookup` -- hey, it was what I had to hand) worked fine.

Answer (score 3):

Telnet.exe cannot be redirected.  The probable reason is that it acts like a terminal, emulating a VT100.  One hint of that you see when you start it, it clears the screen.  That's only possible if a program directly writes to the console screen buffer.  There is no known way to make it behave otherwise, the set term command doesn't have a non-terminal mode option.