# how to execute multiple cammand in command prompt using c#

Tags: .net

I want to execute multiple commands as below:

cd C:\Informatica\9.0\clients\PowerCenterClient\client\bin

pmrep

connect -r rs_01_lab -d Domain_DELLBANPDB01 -n etl_designer -x etl123

using C#...

And i have written a code as below:

```
        Process p = new Process();
        ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe");
        info.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        info.UseShellExecute = false;

        p.StartInfo = info;
        p.Start();

        using (StreamWriter sw = p.StandardInput)
        {
                if (sw.BaseStream.CanWrite)
                {
                    sw.WriteLine("cd C:\Informatica\9.0\clients\PowerCenterClien\client\bin");
                    sw.WriteLine("pmrep");
                    sw.WriteLine("connect -r rs_01_lab -d Domain_DELLBANPDB01 -n etl_designer -x etl123");
                    StreamReader SR = p.StandardOutput;
                    string myString = SR.ReadToEnd();

                    sw.WriteLine("mypassword");
                    sw.WriteLine("use mydb;");
                }
        }
```

But i am not able to write the command in command prompt .

Can you please help me regarding this.

Thanks in advance,
Sunayana

Answer (score 4):

In MS-DOS you can execute multiple commands in one line by separating the commands with an ampersand (&).

```
String strCmdTxt = "/c cd C:\\Informatica\\9.0\\clients\\PowerCenterClient\\client\\bin & pmrep & connect -r rs_01_lab -d Domain_DELLBANPDB01 -n etl_designer -x etl123";
ProcessStartInfo i = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", strCmdTxt);
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo = i;
p.Start();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the parameter in the ProcessStartInfo.

[Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4h05yb.aspx).

Either set the [Arguments Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.arguments.aspx)

Or use [a different overload of the .Start() method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6ak8zt5.aspx).

Comment: If you can't send it as an argument, but it's something that has to be typed into the program, you might be up for a problem. It could be that, similaryly to telnet, your 'pmrep' application doesn't use stdin. Here's a [SO reference for a smiliar problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2212763/c-telnet-process-w-redirected-standard-streams-quits-immediately)